# Serilog not surfacing my custom context properties

Tags: c#, serilog

I am using Serilog with WebApi. I would like to add a Username and class name to every error message.

Here's my code as it stands:

```
public partial class Repo : BaseRepo<db>
{
    public Repo(ILogger logger) : base(logger)
    {
       /// Not working
       //  Logger.ForContext("UserId", currentuser).ForContext<Repo>();
       logger.ForContext("UserId", currentuser).Information("message")
    }
```

The message is rendering as:

```
INF message
```

How do I get `userid: <currentUser>` to show?

Comment: Hi 
I am using serilog with webaip. With every message I would like to add username and class name to every error message.

I am new to serilog

  public partial class Repo : BaseRepo<db>
    {
        public Repo(ILogger logger) : base(logger)
        {
Not working
           //  Logger.ForContext("UserId", currentuser).ForContext<SchoolServiceRepo>();
        
        }

Comment: `Not Working` What does it mean? Are you getting any error?

Comment: I mean when I write Logger.error("Error message").I can't see username (currentuser).

Comment: You need to add `{Properties}` into your configured formatting string in the `LoggerConfiguration`

Comment: I have used PushProperty to add property. LogContext.PushProperty("User Name", currentuser); 

Note: no using statement as below. May I know what issues I will fact if I don't use using statement

public partial class Repo : BaseRepo<db>
{
    public Repo(ILogger logger) : base(logger)
    { 
        LogContext.PushProperty("User Name", currentuser); 
 Note: no using statement as below
  using (LogContext.PushProperty("A", 2))  
    }

Comment: Yes, but its not working, so read my comment more closely  ;) you have done everything right for the property to be present and captured in the log event that gets forwarded to the sink. But for it to appear in the log, you need to use that field in your message rendering template (which might mean specifying one to override a default.). `PushProperty` will do many things you dont want if you use it without a `using`. NB instead of trying to put code in this comment stream, add to your question and then add a simple comment saying "updated OP" or similar.

Comment: On reflection, you do want to do a pushproperty for the username - just not in the ctor - you want to do that in middleware with a using - I trust that's what you're trying to do. As mentioned before, there is a way using DI config to ensure the `ILogger` provisioned to `Class` has the equivalent of `.ForContext<Class>` - I trust you can search it up

Comment: I have created new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712516/serilog-seq-with-autofac-di-loggerconfiguration

Answer (score 5):

The message that is displayed for you depends on the [output template](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#output-templates) of the sink you're using (if supported). If you are using the [Console Sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console), for example, then you need to add `{Properties:j}` to the `outputTemplate` parameter when configuring the sink:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Debug,
        outputTemplate: "[{Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .CreateLogger();
```

---

Also, if you want to display custom properties that you'll add via [`LogContext`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#the-logcontext), then you need to `Enrich.FromLogContext()` too:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Debug,
        outputTemplate: "[{Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();
```

Similarly, if you want to display custom properties that you'll add via [`GlobalLogContext`](https://github.com/augustoproiete/serilog-enrichers-globallogcontext), then you need to `Enrich.FromGlobalLogContext()` too:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Debug,
        outputTemplate: "[{Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .Enrich.FromGlobalLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();
```